# Controls are not added to tabpage VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

I run the following code in the constructor of a window. The "label" gets added but none of the other controls are shown on screen. If I debug the newTab.Controls there are several controls in it. Why don't they show up on the screen and I only see the "label" control.

Thanks

```
Dim graphlist As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    For Each funct As TL_FUNCTION In functionlist
        If (funct.functionname = functi) Then
            If Not (graphlist.Contains(funct.picture)) Then
                graphlist.Add(funct.picture)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    For Each picture In graphlist
        Dim NewTab As New TabPage
        NewTab.Name = picture
        NewTab.Text = NewTab.Name
        Me.TabControl1.Controls.Add(NewTab)
        Me.TabControl1.SelectedIndex = Me.TabControl1.TabCount - 1
        For Each func As TL_FUNCTION In functionlist
            If (func.picture = picture) Then
                Dim label As Label = New Label
                label.Text = func.curve.ToString
                NewTab.Controls.Add(label) 'This label shows up
                Dim key As String
                Dim values() As String
                For Each key In func.values.Keys
                    values = func.values.GetValues(key)
                    For Each value As String In values
                        Dim label2 As New Label
                        label2.Text = key.ToString
                        Dim textb As TextBox = New TextBox
                        textb.Text = value
                        NewTab.Controls.Add(label2) 'this one is not shown on the tab
                        NewTab.Controls.Add(textb) 'this one is not shown on the tab
                    Next value
                Next key
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `.Refresh()` on your tab control once the loop is complete?

Comment: Yes tried the .Refresh(), didn't work.

Comment: `ArrayList` [is obsolete](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5063253/284240).

Comment: What do you mean with arraylist is obsolete?

Comment: Use a `List(of T)` instead of an ArrayList.  Verify you have something in your `func.values.GetValues(key)` array.  If it's empty, those controls aren't getting created.

Comment: Changed the arraylist to list(of T). func.values.getValues is not empty. still nothing is shown.

Comment: What did you use for T?  Just curious, but what kind of object is `func.values` that has a `GetValues` function?

Comment: For <T> I used String. the func.values is a NameValueCollection.

Comment: Well, try placing a breakpoint on `NewTab.Controls.Add(textb)` and look at the values you have.  Also, to notify someone in these comments, type the "@" sign followed by the user name.

Comment: @LarsTech These controls get made and added to the controlslist. They just never show up on the tabpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing the new labels and textboxes *underneath* the new label that you see in the TabPage because you never set their location, so it defaults to point (0, 0).

Try setting the location for the controls:

```
For Each value As String In values
  Dim label2 As New Label
  label2.Text = key.ToString
  label2.Location = New Point(10, NewTab.Controls.Count * 24)

  Dim textb As TextBox = New TextBox
  textb.Text = value
  textb.Location = New Point(label2.Right + 4, label2.Top)

  NewTab.Controls.Add(label2)
  NewTab.Controls.Add(textb)
Next value
```