# C# Generic inheritance from ArrayList

Tags: c#, templates, generics, inheritance

I want to create my own class that inherit from ArrayList. (I want to add some functionality that I need to the ArrayList)

I want my MyArrayList to still be geneirc, means - MyArrayList.

How can I do that?

thanks

Comment: Why can't you inherit from `List<T>` instead?

Comment: Generic... `ArrayList`....? Are you sure that you're using C# and not Java?

Comment: ArrayLists are essentially deprecated. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063156/why-isnt-arraylist-marked-obsolete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is already generic by its defininition, as it's an array of `objects`.

There is nothing more generic then `object` in CLR.

If you mean [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (`<T>`), just use `List<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

IF you want generic list than its better to make use of `List<T>`.

And to add extra function you can make use of extension methods