# Failure to bind the ArrayList to DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  What I want to do is to bind the ArrayList to my DataGrid that I have on my main page.  Things are coming up blank or just erroring out.  Any samples you can give will be a great help.  I also need to have to put an image in one column that is clickable.  That is hardcoded.  Thanks.

In my default.aspx page I have...

<"asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1"> <"/asp:DataGrid>

Then in the default.cs page I have...

```
public class Share : Page
{
    protected TextBox SendExtraDetails;
    protected DataGrid DataGrid1;
            ......

    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            ArrayList alist = (ArrayList)Session["RSArrayList"];
            Session["RSArrayList"] = alist;

            DataGrid1.DataSource = alist;
            DataGrid1.DataBind();

    }
}
```

Comment: What is in the ArrayList? also is there some reason you are not using List?

Comment: Please consider using List<T> as tim suggested. [Why isn't ArrayList marked Obsolete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063156/why-isnt-arraylist-marked-obsolete)

Comment: Yes. [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) is Obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        ArrayList alist = (ArrayList)Session["RSArrayList"];

        DataGrid1.DataSource = alist;
        DataGrid1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Isn't that the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You need `runat="server"` for all ASP.Net server control.

In addition, you need `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` if you do not create columns explicitly such as `BoundColumn`.

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
   runat="server"></asp:DataGrid>
```

***Please consider using GridView with Generic List. DataGrid and ArrayList are Obsolete.***

Comment: Yeah I wish my company where I am at has this.  In which they do not.