# c# How to add a value into a "public arraylist" by a function

Tags: c#

I require a function/method that retrieves some information, and then use the retrieved information in another function.

Below is the principle of my information retriever function:

```
public class StuffIneed 
{
    public ArrayList MyPointList { get; set; }
    public string SomeName { get; set; }
    public TSG3D.Point SomeOtherPoint { get; set; }

    public void DataFetcher()
    {
        //Bunch of loops to check that we are looking at the correct object
        //After the loops I am able to state the value of SomeName and SomeOtherPoint, 
        //but I am unable to add the value of object.current value to the MyPointList as such:
        SomeName = TheObject.Current.Name;
        SomeOtherPoint = TheObject.Current.EndPoint;
        //above works, but below one doesn't
        MyPointList.Add(TheObject.Current.EndPoint);
    }
}
```

I can then use the information in my next function like so:

```
StuffIneed GatheredInfo = new StuffIneed();
GatheredInfo.StuffIneed();
MessageBox.Show(GatheredInfo.SomeOtherPoint.ToString());
```

But I am unable to figure out how to add the values into the `ArrayList`.

Comment: [Observer Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm) may help you...

Comment: *above works, but below one doesn't* - please be more specific about what *doesn't work* mean - does your program throw `NullReferenceException`? Or program doesn't compile? Or do you receive some other error?

Comment: When the debugger reaches the line MyPointList.Add(TheObject.Current.EndPoint);  It will give me an error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". My guess was that since I have stated that MyPointList is either get; or set; then I can't add into it

Comment: ArrayList, avoid it if possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5063253/4180382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to add items to an `ArrayList`, you first have to create instance of `ArrayList` using [new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-operator) keyword and assign it to the `MyPointList` property. Otherwise no `ArrayList` instance exists, `MyPointList` property contains default value `null` (*"no value"*) and hence the *"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"* exception is thrown. You can do this either using property initializer (property will be initialized during `StuffIneed` instance creation):

```
public ArrayList MyPointList { get; set; } = new ArrayList();
```

or in the `DataFetcher` method:

```
MyPointList = new ArrayList();
MyPointList.Add(TheObject.Current.EndPoint);
```

Note that this has nothing to do with `MyPointList` being declared as `get` or `set` - these just let you read (or write) instance of `ArrayList` to/from the `MyPointList` property, but they don't affect the ability to call methods (such as `.Add()`) on the object instance contained in this property.

See also [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Also note that `ArrayList` class is now mostly considered obsolete and [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) or similar [generic classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes) are used instead, e.g.:

```
public List<TSG3D.Point> MyPointList { get; set; } = new List<TSG3D.Point>();
```

They offer better type safety and saves you the hassle of *type-casting* object when reading from it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not show where you initialize the `ArrayList`. If you are encountering a `NullReferenceException`, then perhaps this is the issue?

If so, you could change:

```
public ArrayList MyPointList { get; set; }
```

to:

```
public ArrayList MyPointList { get; set; } = new ArrayList();
```